# Simple jq nested query

Tags: json, jq

Newbie jq nested field question.

I have the following `file.json`

```
{
    "Name": [
            {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": [
                    {
                        "sub-key1": false,
                        "sub-key-2": "val2",
                        "Id": "049f2fa1",
                        "Health": "Good"
                        
                    },
                    {
                         "sub-key1": false,
                        "sub-key-2": "val23",
                        "Id": "049f2c34",
                        "Health": "Bad"
                    }
                ],
                "key3": 2
            }
        ]
   }
```

I am trying to extract the value of the field "Health" for the element of the array with a certain id

tried this

```
cat file.json | jq '.Name[].key2[] | select(.Id=="049f2c34") | .Health'
```

but instead of `Bad` I get empty (the issue has to do with the `.Name[].key2[]` I have also tried `.Name[].key2`)

Comment: Your json is invalid. If I run your command I get an erro message `parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 11, column 17`. So remove the comma before `}` (two times) and a `{` at the beginning

Comment: @jens Right but that is the input file I have (I dont control the input data). Do I have to add {} around it before using jq?

Comment: it must be a valid json

Comment: The input not valid JSON, it has trailing commas in the nested objects. jq can only process JSON, not "looks like JSON". If the input is fixed to be proper JSON, your jq program works and produces "Bad" as output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command-line utility such as https://hjson.github.io/ to transform the quasi-JSON to JSON. There are several such tools. See e.g. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json